# Syntax Highlighting External JS in LCs

Tags: lightning-aura-components

has anyone had any experience importing Syntax Highlighting External JS (like PrismJs, HighlightJs) into Lightning Components?

My use case is to use this external library to show Salesforce Files content (with the body in JSON/JS/CSS etc formats) in my LC.

Right now I am getting the below error when trying to use "https://prismjs.com/"

```
Error- Custom Script Eval error in 'ltng:require' [SecureDOMEvent: [object Event]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, you are not using aura tag `ltng:require`, Please Read [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ltng:require/documentation), to use an external resource like CSS or javascript.

1. You need to upload your files into static Resources.
2. After upload use `ltng:require` aura tag to import file from the static resource, please read the documentation.

Comment: I am already doing that. That's how I am getting the above "Custom Script Eval error"